# Newtonsoft JSON how to dynamically change the date format?

Tags: json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON Serializer and it's great and super fast but I'd like to do a bit more with it. I'm not sure it's possible as all the search I've done comes up to nothing. What I would like is to be able to truncate empty time, so when it's display `2014-01-01 00:00:00.000` I just want `2014-01-01` at the end, so basically cut the entire time when they're all zeros. For now I use this piece of code:

```
DataTable dt = loadData();

// encode the string with Newton JSON.Net 
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
        DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    });
```

Is there a way to format these dates without the time (only when they are all zeros) without affecting the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a custom JsonConverter:

```
class CustomDateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(DateTime));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        if (date.Hour == 0 && 
            date.Minute == 0 && 
            date.Second == 0 && 
            date.Millisecond == 0)
        {
            format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        }
        writer.WriteValue(date.ToString(format));
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>
        {
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Today
        };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new CustomDateConverter() }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dates, settings);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
["2014-06-11 11:56:28","2014-06-11"]
```

Comment: Sounds nice, I will try it... wouldn't it be better to check the time with something like this: `if (date.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") == "00:00:00.000") { ..}`, I don't want to be hit performance wise as my JSON can easily have few thousand rows

Comment: No.  From a pure speed perspective, four integer comparisons is definitely going to be faster than parsing a format string, formatting the date to string then comparing the formatted date to a string of zeros.  From a *practical* speed perspective, it isn't going to make a difference on a few thousand rows.  Use whichever way is more readable/maintainable to you.  If you're really worried about speed, you should be using profiling tools and measuring to find your bottlenecks instead of making premature optimizations.

Comment: So you think 4 integer checks would still be faster than a toString() conversion + check? Actually you're probably right, it might be a bit slower with `ToString()` conversion and string compare, instead of just integer check. I guess that I'll use integer the way you wrote it then... My output could vary and could grow as much as 50k or more so I was just a little concerned of performance.

Comment: Again, if you're worried, use a profiler to find out.  I suspect it isn't going to make much of a difference either way in the grand scheme of things.